# After selected listitem shows details of them on another activity through json?

Tags: android, json, list, android-intent

I have an activity in which i show the list items which come through json. when i click on that item i want to go next activity and show the details related to that particular item name which i select. I am able to show the selected item name as a heading on another page but it doesn't show other things, so please help me to resolve this problem i am new in android. thanks in advance.. !!

here is my code which i did on OnItemClickListener :

```
locationList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String distance = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();
            String country = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country)).getText().toString();
            String city = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city)).getText().toString();
            String phone = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone)).getText().toString();

         // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationDetails.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DISTANCE, distance);
            in.putExtra(TAG_COUNTRY, country);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CITY, city);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE, phone);

            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

and in this i get the name but on other it shows null dont know why i give all the parameters true in it......Please help me.

public class LocationDetails extends Activity{

```
// JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE= "Distance";
    private static final String TAG_CITY = "City";
    private static final String TAG_COUNTRY= "Country";

    private TextView name,phone,address,distance,city,country;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_details);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String Name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String Phone = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE);
        String Address = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ADDRESS);
        String Distance = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DISTANCE);
        String City = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CITY);
        String Country = in.getStringExtra(TAG_COUNTRY);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtView_name);
        phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtView_PhoneField);
        address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtView_AddressField);
        distance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtView_DistanceField);
        city=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtView_CityField);
        country=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtView_CountryField);

        name.setText(Name);
        phone.setText(Phone);
        address.setText(Address);
        distance.setText(Distance);
        city.setText(City);
        country.setText(Country);
    }
}
```

A you told me i did and this happen this are the logcat...

```
04-13 13:01:25.810: D/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 14288 objects / 863832 bytes in 96ms
04-13 13:01:26.570: D/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 19218 objects / 1322032 bytes in 91ms
04-13 13:01:31.370: D/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12650 objects / 889432 bytes in 87ms
04-13 13:01:31.880: I/MapActivity(308): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-13 13:01:31.880: E/MapActivity(308): Couldn't get connection factory client
04-13 13:01:34.220: D/AndroidRuntime(308): Shutting down VM
04-13 13:01:34.220: W/dalvikvm(308): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.linkites.myperspace.Surrounding$1.onItemClick(Surrounding.java:164)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-13 13:01:34.340: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 13:01:37.020: I/Process(308): Sending signal. PID: 308 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you _logged_ the `Strings` in both the current `Activity` and in the `LocationDetails` and checked if they actually have values in them that are not null?

Comment: yeah all they have contain some values

Comment: Then post the code used in the `LocationDetails` activity along with the TAG declarations you have used in both the codes.

Comment: can you tell me how to post my code here again plz????

Comment: Use the edit link at the bottom of the question and post the codes I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: Show your logcat and error line

Comment: @user2092132: Are the `// JSON node keys` declarations the same in both the `Activities`?

Comment: yeah both declearation are same

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this line `Intent in = getIntent();` change to following:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle!=null){
    String Name = bundle.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String Phone = bundle.getString(TAG_PHONE);
    String Address = bundle.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
    String Distance = bundle.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
    String City = bundle.getString(TAG_CITY);
    String Country = bundle.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
}
```

and make sure `String name` will be same while `putExtra` and `getStringExtra`.

Answer (score -1):

Refer the following tutorial, it may be helps you.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

The flow of this tutorial is as follows:

Step-01: First screen shows the details of contact users into the listview

Step-02: You select one user from the listview

Step-03: Then second screen shows the details of that selected user

Go through this tutorial, it will definately helps you...:)

Comment: i tried this but and i dont get my solution that's y i am posting here

Comment: OK...actually I have the same problem as you have mentioned in your question...and I got my solution by following the mentioned tutorial...So I think it will helps you. Check once whether have you add the row file for your listview item or not.